# PHP JSON header adding a line break before output

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, http-headers, homestead

I recently started having a problem where when I use the PHP `header()` command, it is adding a line-break after the command before the output is displayed.

I am using CodeIgniter 2.2.2 and a slightly older version of the CodeIgniter Rest Controller from https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver. I was running on an Apache development environment with XAMPP using PHP 5.6.8. The issue seems to have started when I moved to Laravel Homestead for my environment which has PHP 5.6.7 running on Ubuntu with nginx.

Here is a sample of the code straight from the REST_Controller file:

```
header('Content-Type: '. $this->_supported_formats[$this->response->format] . '; charset=' . strtolower($this->config->item('charset')));
$output = $this->format->factory($data)->{'to_'.$this->response->format}();
```

Without the header line, it works fine, however, it is setting the content type to text/html instead of application/json.

Comment: How exactly does that extra line break manifest? Where/how/when are you confirming it?

Comment: I see the line break when I open an API route (which is basically how I am using CodeIgniter) directly in the browser. The error I am getting is from Angular JS and it says `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`.

Comment: Can you try `curl -i <url here>` (or something similar low-level) to see the pure, raw output?

Comment: It's strange. I thought removing the header solved the problem, but it doesn't. I still get the error that I describe in my last comment. I do not get it in my XAMPP development server though. Could it have something to do with Ubuntu vs Windows or nginx configuration?

Comment: I did the curl and it appears to be fine so now I believe I had the problem all wrong and it has something to do with either the PHP or nginx server configuration on Homestead.

Comment: It's very strange. I cannot figure out what is causing this issue. I have three separate development computers and everything works fine in Homestead on two of the three. I only have this issue on one of them. I am not sure what would make it different.

Comment: did you know why this is happening ? I have a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47742655/why-php-outputs-br-if-i-used-header-or-setcookie-only-with-particular-re)